# Prepending table row into list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my code I have this piece that is part of

```
<ul id="more-menu" class="more-menu arrow_box">
...
</ul>
```

In my .js files I want to add elements to this list and one of them is supposed to be a table with one row that will hold icons, my code for adding table:

```
    $(".more-menu.arrow_box").prepend('</table>' + '</li>');

      $(".more-menu.arrow_box").prepend("<td id='4th'>XYZ</td>");

      $(".more-menu.arrow_box").prepend("<td id='3rd'>XYZ</td>");

      $(".more-menu.arrow_box").prepend("<td id='2nd'>XYZ</td>");

      $(".more-menu.arrow_box").prepend("<td id='1st'>XYZ</td>");

    $(".more-menu.arrow_box").prepend("<li style='background-color: #444444'><table class='ribbon-menu'>");
```

Basically three of them are just a div with span (clickable icons) and one is another arrow box with some elements in it.

And as a result I get:

```
<li style="background-color: #444444"><table class="ribbon-menu"></table></li>
```

folowed by `<td></td>` elements

Comment: Your issues is because your logic is wrong. You can only append *whole* elements at a time, not beginning/end tags. To do what you require, you'd need to append the `li` to the existing `ul`, then the `table` to the `li`, then a `tr`, then each `td`. Alternatively you could just put it in one single string and append that to the `ul`

Comment: Is there any way to append elements like I wanted to?
Problem is because every inside cell is in if-sentence

Comment: You could build it up as a single string and then append that once at the end of your logic

Comment: The solution seems to work as the final string is correctly assembled, but in finished code <li> still gets closed by </li> before any <table> elements

Comment: That will normally occur when you have invalid HTML and the browser renderer is trying to fix it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Properly construct in DOM**

One possibility how to insert the data piece by piece is to insert the full outer elements into the object space and alter them accordingly afterwards.

Thus:

```
$(".more-menu.arrow_box").prepend("<li style='background-color: #444444'><table class='ribbon-menu'></table></li>");
table = $(".more-menu.arrow_box").children().first().find('table')
table.append("<td id='1st'>XYZ</td>")
table.append("<td id='2nd'>XYZ</td>")
table.append("<td id='3rd'>XYZ</td>")
table.append("<td id='4th'>XYZ</td>")
```

Although creating a `<tr>` for the data would be also nice :)